# Android custom font not mapping properly

Tags: android, fonts, mapping, custom-font

I have to implement `Nepali Font` on my application and for that I have used unicode font named `DroidSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf`.The reason I have used this font is that on my `Rooted Galaxy S2 I900`,I have installed  `Resurrection Remix 3.06 JB(AOKP)` which renders `Nepali Font` correctly. And under `system/fonts` folder I have found this `DroidSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf` font,which is responsible for displaying `Nepali Font`.

Further I have used the correct way of using custom font

```
   Typeface font =     
              Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                                       "fonts/DroidSansDevanagari- Regular.ttf");                 
   someTextView.setTypeface(font);
```

And though my application displays the `Nepali Font` it doesn't correctly maps the font.Using same font I get correct mapping on `Rooted Galaxy S2` phone,but I can't get correct mapping on other phones. Let me illustrate this by picture

Correct Mapping

[image: Correct Mapping]

InCorrect Mapping

[image]

So,my question is how to map the font in correct manner as done by my `Rooted Galaxy S2 phone`.For that do I have to look upon `AOKP` project and look upon `EditText` or `Typeface` classes.Please provide me guidance on how to correctly map the fonts on each and every device

Thanks in advance

Comment: As per the information shared by my colleague Mrijan Rimal,I found that the font rendering on custom ROM is done via `harfbuzz rendering` which maps code in correct manner.And he pointed me to this [link]http://code.google.com/p/indic-text-renderer/ which does rendering for `Tamil fonts`.But when same method is followed for `Devnagari font` ,I get issue mentioned on [link] http://code.google.com/p/indic-text-renderer/issues/detail?id=5. I am not an expert on C and C++,due to which I am stuck with `JNI ReferenceTable overflow(max=512` issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For correct font mapping ,[indic text renderer](http://code.google.com/p/indic-text-renderer/) is the best solution I found so far.But before implementing this library,please look upon the solution explained on this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/indic-text-renderer/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=4) in order to render fonts with long texts and without any line spacing in between words

Comment: Is it displaying properly now? Can you provide me the Devanagari ttf file

Comment: @ chaithanya: yes it is displaying the font correctly. I have downloaded the `Devanagari` font from here [link](https://fedorahosted.org/lohit/).And if you have any problem regarding it,do ask me

Comment: Are you rendering? If so how? And what abt matras like "DIN" as "DANI"

Comment: @chaithanya: So far font rendering and mapping is working fine.I have checked with Nepali fonts,it is working as expected

Comment: How are you rendering? Can you specify the procedure or some link/sample

Comment: @chaithanya: I am simply using indic text renderer as usual.But I have done simple modification,like instead of manually copying font to sdcard,I have done it programmatically. I will provide with you whole project,just give me your link

Comment: Hi @laaptu: I am also facing similar problem. Can you please help me too with that code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dipendra: Instead of using indic text font renderer,we have come upon a solution where first the unicode is converted to its equivalent text via this page http://www.ugcs.caltech.edu/~suresh/unicodetokantipur/. Then use that converted text with any unicode font by using Typeface of Android.

Comment: Wow! what a wonderful solution. But it seems I have to be dependent on that page for generating equivalent text. If you dont mind, can I get the source code (algorithm) of it. Anyway that is really great idea.

Comment: @Dipendra : I am in the process of creating my own Nepali Unicode to Kantipur Text. If it works well,I will open source it.