# Android how to make a custom TextView similar to JellyBean(4.1) TextView

Tags: android

I do want to use JellyBean TextView on Android Version lower than JellyBean upto Froyo(2.2) in order to support the native language rendering of text. By saying `want to use` I am referring on how to make a custom `TextView` similar to `JellyBean TextView`.JellyBean TextView easily renders the native language(in my case Nepali) font.You may suggest using `TypeFace.createFromAsset` mechanism but while doing so the `font glyph` is not properly rendered as I have stated on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635080/android-custom-font-not-mapping-properly).

I again want to clarify `stackoverflow moderators` that I am not asking the same question,but I want to know the technique on how to port back `JellyBean TextView` to older devices(<4.1).